# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

I keep struggling with importing the pyqtgraph module. It's really only about the import:
`pip3 install pyqtgraph` is not working.
My code:
`from PyQt5 import QtGui`  
`import PyQt5`
`import numpy as np`
`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox`
`import pyqtgraph as pg`
`import time`  
leaves:

```
<ipython-input-37-14dc06d126e4> in <module>
     31 import numpy as np
     32 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
---> 33 import pyqtgraph as pg
     34 import time
     35 import sys

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your module gets installed to another `Python` version than what `PYTHONPATH` points to.

Try `pip3 list -v | grep "pyqtgraph"` on Unix-like `OSs`, or  `pip3 list -v | findstr "pyqtgraph"` on `Windows`.

The directory location that will be shown will be different to your `PYTHONPATH`. Set your location to `PYTHON3.7` dir and it should solve your problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) on how you can do that.

Comment: unfortenately this happens: ``` pip3 list -v | findstr "pyqtgraph" ```   with error:      ``` pip3 list -v | findstr "pyqtgraph"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: the syntax error is between pip3 and list.. I dont know why ``` doesnt give me script format

Answer (score 0):

The error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqtgraph.examples'" will also appear if the script to be executed if named pyqtgraph.py.